# Anylogic referencing columns in a collection

Tags: anylogic

I am using a collection to represent available trucks in a system. I am using a `1` or `0` for a given index number, using a `1` to say that indexed truck is available. I am then trying to assign that index number to a customer ID. I am trying to randomly select an available truck from those listed as available. I am getting an error saying the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable and highlighting the portion of the code reading `Available_Trucks() = 1`. This is the code:

`agent.ID = randomWhere(Available_Trucks, Available_Trucks() = 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing it won't work... randomWhere when applied to a collection of integers, will return the element of the collection (in this case 1 or 0).
So doing

```
randomWhere(Available_Trucks,at->at==1); //this is the right synthax
```

will return 1 always since that's the value of the number chosen in the collection. So what you need is to get the index of the number of the collection that is equal to 1. But you will have to create a function to do that yourself... something like this (probably not the best way but it works: `agent.ID=getRandomAvailbleTruck(Available_Trucks);`

And the function getRandomAvailbleTruck will take as an argument a collection (arrayList probably).. it will return -1 if there is no availble truck

```
int availableTrucks=count(collection,c->c==1);
if(availableTrucks==0) return -1;
int rand=uniform_discr(1,availableTrucks);
int i=0;
int j=0;
while(i<rand){
    if(collection.get(j)==1){
        i++;
        if(i==rand){
            return j;
        }   
    }
    j++;
}
return -1;
```

Now another idea is to instead of using 0 and 1 for the availability, you can use correlative numbers: 1,2,3,4,5 ... etc and use a 0 if it's not available. For instance if truck 3 is not availble, the array will be 1,2,0,4,5 and if it's available it will be 1,2,3,4,5.
In that case you can use

```
agent.ID=randomTrue(available_trucks,at->at>0);
```

But you will get an error if there is no available truck, so check that.

Nevertheless, what you are doing is horrible practice... And there is a much easier way to do it if you put the availability in your truck if your truck is an agent... 
Then you can just do

```
Truck truck=randomWhere(trucks,t->t.available==1);
if(truck!=null)
     agent.ID=truck.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely follow what you are saying and thank you for going above and beyond. I am new to Anylogic and just getting back into simulation in general from about a 7 year break. Really appreciate you going above and beyond and adding availability makes perfect sense. I think I marked this as answered but let me know if I did not, I am new here as well. Thanks again.

Comment: For some reason, this is always returning null for truck. trucks is my agent and this is the code I used. Truck_ID is the truck ID, ID is the customer ID, and Available is the variable on truck that I flip to 1 when it is available.

Comment: Trucks truck = randomWhere(trucks, t->t.Available == 1);
if (truck!=null)
 agent.ID = truck.Truck_ID;
if (truck == null)
 agent.ID = 3;

Comment: I used the if null it == 3 just to see that it was changing the variable from 0 and it is.

Comment: I changed a my agent to Trucks and used this code. Now it is not returning null, but the agent.ID remains 0 after it passes through. I had t setting the value to 3 if it was null to double check. 

Trucks trucks = randomWhere(Trucks, t->t.Available == 0);

if (trucks!=null)

 agent.ID = trucks.Truck_ID;

Comment: you have a bug.. it can be for so many reasons that it's impossible to help without actually looking at your model

Comment: Hi, sorry for being so new. I isolated the issue to where I am adding the unique number to the agent. The code I am using is on exit: agent.Truck_ID = TruckCount; TruckCount is correctly increasing every time an agent passes through. I have a resource being siezed to eliminate the possibility of double numbering as there are two places trucks enter the system. Truck_ID is staying at whatever I initialized it as. I apologize if this is something really simple, agent.Available = 1; that follows this appears to be working properly so I am guessing it is syntax. Thanks for all the help.